# Set SONAME after linkage

Tags: linux, shared-libraries, gnu

Consider the following creation of a shared library. Is is possible to do

```
g++ -shared -o __targets/libfoo.so libfoo.cpp
some command that sets SONAME of __targets/libfoo.so to libfoo.so.X
```

instead of

```
g++ -shared -o __targets/libfoo.so -Wl,-soname,libfoo.so.X libfoo.cpp
```

The problem is that the version number is not known to the module that issues the linking command.

Comment: My situation is a bit different though: I have a third party library that has no soname, and I cannot have it relinked.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I don't think this is a good idea in the first place, but if you really need it there is a program called [patchelf](https://github.com/NixOS/patchelf).  There's even a chance that it's already packaged as a part of your distribution.  So you should be able to set `soname` at the second step by invoking the following command:

`patchelf --set-soname libfoo.so.X __targets/libfoo.so`

Comment: They should update patchelf README and I should have checked patchelf help.

Comment: I'll be able to accept and award the answer in 19 hours

Comment: @AdamTrhon  That happens.  The man page also mentions it.  The feature seems to date back to mid-2014.  On the bright side, you can always make things better for others.  They seem to accept pull-requests.  So in theory, you could update that README by yourself.  Thank you for the acceptance though.